# How to order a string[] in c++

Tags: c++, string

The input is string[] like below.

> "CSE111: CSE110 MATH101"
>
> "CSE110:"

I need to order the strings based on some logic. For example my output should be a `string[]` like

> "CSE110","MATH122","CSE111"

My question is

1. While scanning through the input array, if one string is picked to be the first string of the output array, then how do I skip all occurrences of that particular string, while I continue to process the `string[]` for the second output string etc..

Eg:

Input:

> "CSE111: CSE110 MATH101"
>
> "CSE110:"

If CSE110 is picked to be the first string in the output, then when I scan through the input string[] for the second string to be a part of output, I should not consider CSE110.

How can I achieve this? The answer I am looking forward to is something like:

1. Store the input in a string[]
2. loop through the strings one by one using strtok or stringstream >> operator.
3. Once the first string is found ...blah blah blah ....

Hope my question is clear enough. I will be glad to provide more details.

Edit1:More Explanation

The strings represent the order in which the classes need to taken . If a class has  pre-requisite , the pre-requisite has to be taken first. ie.  if Input is

```
"CSE111: CSE110 MATH101"
"CSE110:"
```

The class CSE111 has a pre-requisite of CSE110 MATH101 . So I need to consider first CSE1110(No Pre-requisite) - MATH101((No Pre-requisite) and then CSE111 . (Further Ties can broken in alphabetical order. )
I hope this helps..

Comment: I can't understand the logic you're trying to explain at all.  I do think it would be extremely useful for you to consider whether these are in fact two separate problems: 1) parsing the inputs and storing them in a data structure, then 2) generating the appropriate output based on the input data.

Comment: Yes , it is correct. I am looking forward to solutions to both the 2 problems

Comment: As God is my witness, I can't help but look at this and think, "Maybe if you wrote this as a `Makefile`... -_-;

Comment: @Mike: There's no `string[]` data type in makefiles.

Comment: You don't need one.  Your input format already looks close to a Makefile, so you could probably use a Bash or Perl script to preprocess it.  Output, per rule, may well just be `printf $@`.  So you use lines of output instead of a list of strings.  I don't think it'll do the alphabetizing, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I hopefully got it now: For a string of the form `A: B C D`, the course `A` has `B`, `C`, and `D` as prerequisites.

In that case you want a mapping from a course to its prerequisites, e.g.:

```
typedef std::set<std::string> CourseSet;
typedef std::map<std::string, CourseSet> Prerequisites;
```

Now you can fill a `Prerequisites` by tokenizing, using the first part as the key and a `CourseSet` as the value.

As it seems that you just want one of the possible orders for all courses in the input, you could then do the following:

- complete the prerequisites for the courses (i.e. include the courses they indirectly depend on)
- now `a>b` if `a` has `b` as a prerequisite
- if `b` doesn't have `a` as a prerequisite use e.g. the lexicographical order

Comment: I think he's also trying to specify the first value, with the rest of the array sorted normally.

Comment: Well I cannot use std:sort() as It is not a simple sorting that I need to do . The strings represent the order in which the classes need to taken . If a class has  pre-requisite , the pre-requisite has to be taken first. ie.  if Input is 


    "CSE111: CSE110 MATH101"
    "CSE110:"

The class CSE111 has a pre-requisite of CSE110 MATH101 . So I need to consider first CSE1110(No Pre-requisite) - MATH101((No Pre-requisite) and then CSE111 . (Further Ties can broken in alphabetical order. )
I hope this helps..

Comment: @Eternal: I get your prerequisites now, but for now i only see a list of dependencies - what is the actual input for which you want to generate the course-list?

Comment: Input:
classSchedule={
"CSE121: CSE110",
"CSE110:",
"MATH122:",
}
Output:

{"CSE110","CSE121","MATH122"}

Comment: @Eternal: Updated under the assumption that every course with no prerequisites also appears as `"FOO:"` in the input - at least your first example in the question doesn't have that form.